# Snakemake expand() only applies on the first element of a list

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm trying to expand on two set of files that have a similar name structure, only one is longer than the other.

```
x=expand(
[
    "results/qc/{u.sample}.foo.txt",
    "results/qc/{u.sample}.foo.bar.txt",
],
u=samples.itertuples()
)
print(x)
```

The result being:

```
['results/qc/A.foo.txt', 'results/qc/B.foo.txt', 'results/qc/C.foo.txt']
```

Only the first one is expanded, which is a behavior I could understand if it was a wildcard inside the `{ }`. But [this](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#the-expand-function) from the official Snakemake documentation indicates it's not.

`samples` is a 1-column pandas dataframe containing 3 values: A,B,C.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't look into the source code, my guess is for each filename you want to insert variable in, it loops each element in the variable again. So `itertuples()` returns an iterator, for first filename `{u.sample}.foo.txt` the iterator already hits the end, then for the next filename `{u.sample}.foo.bar.txt` there is no element remaining in the iterator. A simple solution is extracting all elements in iterator as a list

```
x=expand(
[
    "results/qc/{u.sample}.foo.txt",
    "results/qc/{u.sample}.foo.bar.txt",
],
u=list(samples.itertuples())
)
print(x)
```

Comment: Thank you, it did work just fine adding `list()` !